# AppleScript that used to work reported as Broken on newer OSX version

Tags: macos, security, applescript

An Applescript that used to work on OSX 10.6.8 is reported as broken when run on 10.8.6. The script is compiled as an Application on 10.6.8. Why is this?

Running the .applescript text version of the script in the editor works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the new GateKeeper feature in OSX that only allows signed applications to be installed, or even just programs downloaded from the Mac App Store.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5290

For normal programs you get a security warning telling you that the program cannot be run because it isn't signed.

With Apple scripts it seems that you simply get an error telling you that the program is broken.

To fix this this:

- Open System Preferences
- Security and Privacy:

  - Under the General tab set:

    - Allow Applications Downloaded from: **Anywhere**

[image]